# Google Maps JS API 3 Uncaught Security Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm receiving the following error in the console when loading Google Maps asynchronously in a Rails App using Turbolinks (not sure if turobolinks is related to the error). The map loads as expected, but I can't seem to clear this error.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "https://example.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

The initialization script is very similar to the vanilla example in the API docs, except that the loadScript function is triggered on the turbolinks page:load event.

```
function initialize() {
  var lat = $('#map-canvas').data('lat');
  var long = $('#map-canvas').data('long');
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  if ( $( "#map-canvas" ).length ) { //only initialize on map pages
    if (typeof google == "undefined") { //prevent duplicate loading
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
        '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    }else{
      initialize();
    }
  }
}


  $(document).on("ready page:load", loadScript);
```

Comment: can you post a link to the page?

Comment: sure, here's an example: https://anchorage.io/locations/potato-harbor

Comment: I don't get this error

Comment: Interesting, on firefox I get "Error: Permission denied to access property 'gm-master'".  I get the original error on chrome. Thanks anyway for checking it out.

Comment: I don't see an error either. When you see the issue is your site loading over http and not https?